# nativescript-plugin-firebase Cloud Messaging app crashes if tap the message when app in foreground

Tags: android, angular2-nativescript

I use nativescript-plugin-firebase for Cloud Messaging.

On android, if I get the message when the app is running in the background or closed, and I tap on the message (notification), the app opens.

However, if the message arrives and I open the app manually and then tap on the message, then the app crashes.

In other words, the app only crashes if u tap on the message when the app is running.

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to destroy activity {kidcare.technology/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: GridLayout(3) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: Page(2)

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {kidcare.technology/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: GridLayout(3) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: Page(2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5030)
    at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: GridLayout(3) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: Page(2)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1138)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1134)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onDestroy(NativeScriptActivity.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8181)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4986)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I fixed it by change the android:launchMode to "singleTop" in AndroidManifest.xml 
Deleted the platform>android folder and rebuild the app